# AngularJS Unique Filter then update all Records

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-filter

I'm tasked with showing a list of records with AngularJS like so:

```
$scope.colours = [
  {id:'1', name: 'red', active: true },
  {id:'2',  name: 'blue', active: false },
  {id:'3',  name: 'green', active: true },
  {id:'4',  name: 'red', active: false }
];
```

and giving the user the ability to show/hide them via a checkbox by the category(or in the example colour) they sit under.  So I've taken the data and displayed some checkboxes using the Angular-UI Unique filter but when I toggle the "Red" category I want to toggle All Records that have "red" as the value.

I'm guessing I need to loop through the records and do it manually on checkbox change is there a more Angular way to do this?

Also is this even good practice to even use Angular Filters to filter out results in a ng-repeat for large datasets?

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/QXk9E/

Regards

Comment: Are the colors predefined or they depend upon data send from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom filter that sorts by multiple values. This will allow you to remove the `active` property from all of your data as well. Let's call it `manyToMany` and have it take three parameters:

1. an array of objects to sort
2. a string to specify which property on those objects to sort by
3. an object hash of boolean properties whose keys correlate to possible values of the property. The value for any given property will be `true` if the sort property should include results matching that key.

Here is what the filter would look like:

```
.filter('manyToMany',function(){
    return function(arrInput,strProperty,objMany){
        var arrFiltered = [];
        for(var i=0,max=arrInput.length;i<max;i++){
            if(objMany[arrInput[i][strProperty]] === true){
                arrFiltered.push(arrInput[i]);
            }
        };
        return arrFiltered;
    }
});
```

Then create a new object in the scope that will be used for the `objMany`:

```
$scope.activeColors = {};
```

And in your HTML, have your checkboxes set values on that object based on the color names from the unique repeater:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="activeColors[colour.name]" />{{colour.name}}
```

And use the filter like:

```
<div ng-repeat="colour in colours | manyToMany:'name':activeColors">{{colour}}</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/R5qW5/)

Comment: Yes that works very well thanks and with little code although I'd be interested to know why the manyToMany filter runs twice when toggling the checkboxes, thoughts? Heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/CGeg5/

Comment: That has to do with the way that Angular's `$digest` loop works internally. It's somewhat complicated but each time there is a `$digest` on `$rootScope`, it and all of its child scopes' watchers are checked. If new values are set during that process (which is often in the case of a filter), it checks them again to make sure the model has stabilized.  See [this link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) for more.

Comment: sh0ber, great code, though it doesn't work for radio buttons. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your model is incorrect. What you need is a list of items that the user has filtered based on the criteria - in this case the color.

In such a case, you should not put the `active` property on each of the objects. Instead, what you should do is the following:

**Step 1**
Define the model as:

```
$scope.colors = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "red"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "blue"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "green"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "red"
    }
];
```

Note that I have not added the `active` property to each of the objects yet.

**Step 2**
Next, you define another model that keeps track of the active filters:

```
$scope.activeFilters = [];
```

Initially, this will be empty but it entries will be added / removed from this depending on the selection state of each of the filters.

**Step 3**
You then have a function that will inform if the checkbox is active or not

```
$scope.isChecked = function (item) {
    return $scope.activeFilters.indexOf(item) !== -1;
};
```

**Step 4**
You then define a function that will add / remove the filter items:

```
$scope.toggleFilter = function (filterItem) {
    //Check if the filter item already exists in the list of active filters
    if ($scope.activeFilters.indexOf(filterItem) !== -1) {
        //Yes, the filter item already exists.
        //Since we are in toggle mode, we remove the item from the active filters
        $scope.activeFilters.splice($scope.activeFilters.indexOf(filterItem), 1);
    } else {
        //No entry does not exist.
        //Since we are in toggle mode, we add the entry to the list
        $scope.activeFilters.push(filterItem);
    }
};
```

Each time any of the checkbox is set / unset, you call this function.

**Step 5**
Next, you define a function that sets the filters data based on the active filters:

```
$scope.filterData = function () {
    //This will be the model that will be used to display the final or
    //filtered data
    //Reset it each time this is called
    $scope.filteredColors = [];

    //If there are no active filters, show all the colors
    if ($scope.activeFilters.length === 0) {
        $scope.filteredColors = $scope.colors;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.colors.length; i++) {
            //Check if the color name is requested in the active filter
            if ($scope.activeFilters.indexOf($scope.colors[i].name) !== -1) {
                //The color has been actively set in the filter. Display it
                $scope.filteredColors.push($scope.colors[i]);
            }
        }
    }
};

//When the controller is initialized, we need to call the above function once to
//get the colors to display. Since no filters are active initially, all colors
//will be shown
$scope.filterData();
```

**Step 6**
Each time the active filters change, you need to recalculate the colors to display - a simple watch will suffice

```
$scope.$watch('activeFilters.length', function () {
    //Check for invalid values
    if ($scope.activeFilters === null || $scope.activeFilters === undefined) {
        //Nothing to do
        return;
    } else {
        //Re-calculate the colors to display
        $scope.filterData();
    }
});
```

Thus, each time a filter is set / reset, the list of colors to display will be re-calculated.

**Step 7**
You now need a model that will contain unique colors - for the filter

```
$scope.uniqueColors = [];

for (var j = 0; j < $scope.colors.length; j++) {
    if ($scope.uniqueColors.indexOf($scope.colors[j].name) === -1) {
        //The color does not exist. Add it
        $scope.uniqueColors.push($scope.colors[j].name);
    }
}
```

**Final Step**
The view - based on the model and functions that we have defined earlier, you now need to define your view accordingly.

```
<label ng-repeat="c in uniqueColors">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isChecked(c)" ng-click="toggleFilter(c)">
    {{c}}
</label>

<div ng-repeat="f in filteredColors">
    {{f}}
</div>
```

EDIT: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dRMBN/) is a fiddle of the same.

Comment: Incredibly complete and nice answer.  However it seems a bit long to simply toggle a filter (unless I'm misreading the question).